# Facebook SDK Import errors

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook

I have just imported the Facebook SDK in my eclipse as a library as I have read to do.

The problem is the facebook project is full of errors. For instance, in the AccessToken.java it can't import "android.annotation", and like this, other files with other imports...

I have tried setting the java compilator to 1.6 and it doesn't do anything. Then I read this android.annotation is just avaible for api level 16, but that api level is for a Android 4.x.x and I don't want that... I want to use this sdk in at least Android 2.2.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: May be it works : Try with add support library. Right click of project then select android tools then select add support library. After that select properties and goto java build path > order and export select android version, private lib and dependenceis and move on top and select checkbox then apply and ok. Do clean.

Comment: It didn't do anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a project in any other work space and move all the FILES into that project. It fixed my issue with latest facebook sdk.

Comment: add necessary details to the manifest also. Just copy each file to the new work space! layouts, class files etc

Answer (score 0):

Even though you don't want api level 16 it could be that you need the SDK Platform of that API level from the SDK Manager, because now those classes are unknown to Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

just delete the dependency from the bulid path->configure build path-> Library-> dependency

and also check if any red cross sign in your library tab. if any re sign is available, then delete this. may be its taking the refrence from other application.

Comment: Did it and nothing happened

Comment: what the error you getting. can you send me ur code.so that i can check it.