# when i import facebook sdk it gets more errors

Tags: android

when i import facebook sdk in eclipse it gives me errors.
I have aready tried these posts.

"[difficulty in importing the facebook-android-sdk into eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375211/difficulty-in-importing-the-facebook-android-sdk-into-eclipse)"

"[Facebook SDK Import errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20070525/facebook-sdk-import-errors)".

Answer (score 0):

There might be chance of missing some files. Download latest sdk and save it were your eclipse is saved. Then, import your facebook sdk. Else restart ur eclipse and try again.
Note: eclipse and facebook sdk location should be in same path.

Comment: when i download the latest one it gives error like "failed -Network error"

Comment: latest sdk is not downloaded.